# How do we use MongoDB in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, nosql

Does anybody know how to create a rails application that use noSql database?
We do rails new app_name -d mysql for using mysql database, I need to know what command I should fire in case of noSql database.how to configure and connect to that database and how to use table from it. I need reference link to study. Can anybody help me out?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Googling “mongodb rails”?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I am concerned you will have to create a new Rails project excluding active record:

```
rails new my_app --skip-active-record
```

then you can follow the configuration steps from Mongoid:

http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html

Comment: Mongoid is a popular [Object Mapper for use with MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Language+Center#RubyLanguageCenter-ObjectMappers) but not the only one.

Comment: Hello Arthur I tried above link but it gives me following error .. **/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:153:in `block in instance_delegate': undefined method `each' for "[]":String (NoMethodError).**

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started should get you started.